# How to put an Array object into JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have written the following Javascript code.  It's the best I could do to get my data formatted as valid JSON:

```
var roles = getSelectedRoles(); // returns an Array object

/* TODO: Find a better way to get the roles into my JSON data */
var rolesString = '["' + roles[0] + '"';
if (roles.length > 1)
    for (var i = 1; i < roles.length; i++)
        rolesString += ',"' + roles[i] + '"';
rolesString += ']';                        

var lid = $('#lid').val();

var json = '{ "id": "' + lid + '", "roles":' + rolesString + '}';
```

As you can see, I am building my JSON with string concatenation looping thru my Array object.  This is so ugly and it seems like there ought to be a clean way of inserting my Array data into my JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If its just inserting array object into another object then:

```
var selRoles = getSelectedRoles(); 
var lid = $('#lid').val();  
var json = {
 id:lid ,
 roles: selRoles
};
```

If you need the whole object to be represented as a String then you can use Douglas Crockford's [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) to achieve the same.

Include the js file mentioned above in your page and then you use:

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(json) //json is from previous code.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonObj = {
    id: lid,//$('#lid').val()
    roles:roles // getSelectedRoles()
}
var jsonStr = json_encode(jsonObj);
</script>
```

You can find the function: [json_encode](http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode:457) at here

Answer (score 0):

You could use the join function of your roles' array:

```
var rolesString = '["' + roles.join('", "') + '"]';
```

Answer (score 0):

Current browsers offer a JSON object type which can make this sort of thing trivial (JSON.stringify(obj)) .. see, for example, [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/json.shtml)